# Which web server software to use

Tags: apache, lamp

I have VPS with 3 websites hosted.
Only one is a high traffic with around 3000 visits/day.

```
VPS Specs
CPU: 2,3GHz
RAM: 512MB
SSD: 20GB
```

I configure it to use 2GB swap with swappiness 3, so it will use it only when RAM is critical.
Swap is almost non-used because everything consumes about 280-350MB RAM on medium load.

Currently I use LAMP -

```
Linux Debian 7 Wheezy AMD64
Apache2
MySQL
PHP
```

Other are Postfix, Webmin, dove-cot, APF Firewall, DDoS Deflate.
It is run via a Cloudflare network for best performance.

Now, I heard good things about ngnix and Light-httpd.
Which one I should choose, or to stay with Apache? 
Performance are not very good with a much users online, If I see good, fu*king Apache uses separated sub-process for every visitors online? 
That's ridiculous.

So please, recommend be the best one to use on current server? Thank you in advance!
Please note that I use a lot subdomains, so I need that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the following white paper http://www.whisperdale.net/11-nginx-vs-cherokee-vs-apache-vs-lighttpd.html

Comment: Very nice. :) Thank you! I would chose ngnix then, do you maybe known is ngnix secure as Apache is?

Comment: Thanks. :) I doing migration to ngnix now.

Answer (score 0):

You should monitor the server first.
Which process is taking up resources? Apache? My guess is that MySQL would be the culprit if lots of queries are being made, or misconfigured.
Also, consider upgrade to at least 1Gb, most VPS provides will not charge that much for such a difference (if they do, change provider).

Comment: Is there some light alternative to MySQL? I'm on DIgitalOcean, and I pay as much I can afford, so upgrade is not possible for now.

Comment: Well, it really depends if you're using some big database or not. SQLite might be an option, but I can't really say without knowing the whole code/site.

Comment: I found MariaDB server as lighter and faster alternative.